# How to write a function in javascript to modify values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have to Create a function that will replace the isComplete flag from false to true in the below array of work having name equal to CCF...I'm new to javaScript I'll be thankful for your help.

```
     const works = [
     {name:"CCS",workStatus:{isComplete:true}},
     {name:"CCB",workStatus:{isComplete: false}},
     {name:"CCF",workStatus:{isComplete: false}}
      ]
```

output must be

```
       const works = [
       {name:"CCS",workStatus:{isComplete:true}},
       {name:"CCB",workStatus:{isComplete: false}},
       {name:"CCF",workStatus:{isComplete: true}}
      ]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: That file is not JSON, it's JavaScript source code. If it were JSON, it wouldn't have `const works =` and would have the property names in double quotes. (And if it were JSON, this would be an easier problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use forEach loop

```
works.forEach(function(item){
        if(item.name === "CCF"){//Change the condition as per your need.

            item.workStatus.isComplete = true;//add null checks
        }
    })
```

The code can also be wrapped into a function.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const works = [
     {"name":"CCS","workStatus":{"isComplete":true}},
     {"name":"CCB","workStatus":{"isComplete": false}},
     {"name":"CCF","workStatus":{"isComplete": false}}
      ];


function test(){
  works[0].workStatus.isComplete=false;
  works[1].workStatus.isComplete=true;
  console.log(works); 
}
```

```html
<button onClick =test()>Click me</button>
```

This is how you change values of JSON object/Array